# Ignoring the symbol ° in R devtools function document()

Tags: r, special-characters, devtools, roxygen2, roxygen

I would like to create a package for internal usage (not to distribute somewhere). One of my functions contains the line

`if (data$unit[i] != "°C") {`

It works perfectly in the script, but if I want to create the documentation for my package using document() from devtools, i get the error

> Error in parse(text = lines, keep.source = TRUE, srcfile = srcfilecopy(file, *path_to_my_code*: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
>
> 279:     if (! is.na(data$unit[i]){
>
> 280:       if (data$unit[i] != "
>
> addition: Warning message:
>   In readLines(con, warn = FALSE, n = n, ok = ok, skipNul = skipNul) :
>     invalid input found on input connection '*path_to_my_code*'

If I delete the °-character, document() works. But I need this character there, so this is not an option.

When using double-\ in the if-clause, my function doesn't detect °C anymore as shown here:

```
test <- c("mg/l", "°C")
"\\°C" %in% test
[1] FALSE
```

If I use `tryCatch`, the documentation is also not created.

Replacing `"°C"` by `gsub(pattern = '\\\\', replacement = "", x = '\\°C')` causes the function to crash at the double-\ .

How can I tell document() that everything is fine and it should just create the files?

Comment: Try setting "Encoding: UTF-8" in your description, or using a unicode escape. It's surprising that this doesn't always fail for you, since devtools loads yours scripts in the same way as a R. 

If that doesn't help, try making a reprex.

Comment: Thank you very much, setting "Encoding: ISO-8859-1" in the description file worked for me. The reason it did not always fail might have something to do with the fact I was using RStudio (which asks you in which encoding you want to save your code if it detects special characters). Since I created my scripts a longer time ago, I forgot about that.

Comment: I strongly recommend against using anything other than UTF8